# How to check if the remote image changes? (Android caches images indefinitely)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm losing my mind trying to get this to work.

So, it seems that, in React Native, Android will cache the image of a certain URL forever. If I change the image at that URL, it will not change in the app for Android, but iOS handles it just fine.

I know about the trick of just adding

```js
`?time=${Date.now()}`
```

to the end of the `uri` specified in `source={{ uri }}`

However, that will fetch a new image every time, which technically works, but then the user has to wait for the image to load every time. I could add an `ActivityIndicator` placeholder while the image loads, but if I could properly cache the image then that `ActivityIndicator` wouldn't be shown nearly as often, making for better UX.

I would like to know if there's a way to check if the remote image has changed, within the constraints of Expo SDK 33 (no `react-native link`). I can handle the cache busting just fine if there is such a method, it would just require incrementing a persistently saved integer whenever a change is detected, and appending that to the `uri`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a different approach is necessary.

I fixed this issue in the backend. If you have access to the backend, that's great!

What I did was create an API that would take in the path to the image that I wanted, and it redirected to that image, with `?lastUpdated=<modified>` appended to the URL, where `<modified>` is the time at which that file was last modified. This way, it automatically cache busts the image whenever the image is changed!